# Circular object initialization in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

Wouldn't it be nice if I could do this in Ruby?

```
class Type
  attr_accessor :weak_against, :strong_against

  def initialize(weak_against, strong_against)
    @weak_against = weak_against
    @strong_against = strong_against
  end
end

Fire = Type.new([Water], [Grass])
Water = Type.new([Grass], [Fire])
Grass = Type.new([Fire], [Water])
```

But I can't.

```
=> type.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Water (NameError)
```

Anyone know a work around?

Comment: Using `Type` as a class name would be very, horribly, confusing when discussing the code. Classes should represent an object, a thing, not an attribute of a thing, and should be named accordingly. Something like `Element` could apply since water and fire are elements. Grass is an outlier but you can see the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
class Type
  attr_accessor :weak_against, :strong_against
end

Fire = Type.new
Water = Type.new
Grass = Type.new

Fire.weak_against = Water
Fire.strong_against = Grass

Water.weak_against = Grass
Water.strong_against = Fire

Grass.weak_against = Fire
Grass.strong_against = Water
```

Comment: Been putting it off because it isn't nearly as pretty code, but it does work. It's been nearly a week. Here ya go.